# Angular Submit by pressing Enter key or click button

Tags: html, angular

I would like that when i press the enter key or the log in button to submit. Only the click on the button is working at the time of submitting.
Can anyone help me get both of them working?

```
<div class="BLog">
            <div class="Log" (click)="Log()">
                Log in
            </div>
</div>
```

```
async Log() {
    let self = this;
    let ident = {
      username: self.username,
      password: self.password,
      client_id: "task",
      grant_type: "password",
    }
    let aux = await self.logService.postAt(ident);
    if(aux) self.router.navigate(['first']);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it without form, 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4k2xr4

```
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';

  Log() {
    this.name  = "Logged In"
  }

  handleKeyboardEvent(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
      this.Log()
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<div class="BLog" (keydown)="handleKeyboardEvent($event)">
  <input value="type and press enter">
    <div class="Log">
        Log in
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to wire this up in a form and add a `button` of type submit.

```html
<form (submit)="Log()">
   <div class="BLog">
            <div class="Log">
                <button type="submit">Log in</button>
            </div>
   </div>
</form>
```